# Convert Decision Tree to PMML using sklearn2pmml with default condition

Tags: python, scikit-learn, business-rules, pmml

I am working with `sklearn2pmml` in python to convert a decision tree trained using `scikit-learn` library into PMML  file. I have a data frame which has 4 columns as show below

```
X1  | X2  |  A1  |  Y 
0.2.  0.3   alpha.  0
0.3.  0.1.  alpha   0
0.9   0.2.  beta    1
```

and so on. Here `Y` is the binary label.`X1`,`X2` are the numerical input. `A1` is a string column. I have trained a decision Tree on `Y,X1,X2` and I am able to write it as a PMML file.

However I need to introduce a default condition in the PMML that if the variable A1 = 'beta'  then return X1 itself as score else use the scikit learn decision tree to get the score

Is it possible to do so using `sklearn2PMML` or by manually creating the node in the PMML file ?

Here is a working code to generate the decision tree and pmml

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn2pmml import PMMLPipeline
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 2)), columns=['X1','X2']
df['Y'] = np.random.randint(0,2,size=15)
df['A1'] = 'alpha'
df['A1'][0:50]='beta'
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("classifier",DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2,random_state=42))
])
pipeline.fit(df[['X1','X2']],df['Y']
sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "SimpleDecisionTree.pmml", with_repr = True)
```